# NgRx Store select after subscribe not completing

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I am trying to get data from ngrx store , but as soon as the subscription completes it must go to finalize , and that is not happening

```
    const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors(state);
    this.subscription = this.store.select(selectAll)
    .pipe(
          finalize(() => {
            console.log('completed')
          }),
      .subscribe(
        o => {
          //perform some action
        },
        error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
```

Comment: The store remains "open". It'll never complete unless you do `take(1)`, `first`, `timeout` or other to close the stream.

Comment: thanks for response, but i need to make store open to listen changes done from other functions , as inside subscribe i am assigning some value (array of objects )to variables that is shown to view on change of it, any solution to this?

Comment: you wanna listen to some actions and then do some control?

Comment: @anupkumar: I can see `,` in the closing of `pipe()`.Can you confirm that the code is correct. Remove that `,` before `.subscribe` and let me know using `@` in comment section

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to some actions in the store you can try this, imagine you want to listen to CREATE_SUCCESS action and then do some control when your entity is created

```
import { Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as entityActions from './actions'; 


constructor(private actions$: Actions) {
  this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(entityActions.EntityActionTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS)
   ).subscribe(() => { 
     // code executed every time there is a success creation action dispatched 
  })
}
```